# How to pass a list of data between views in MVC 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, viewbag

I am building my first MVC app after following the Music Store tutorial and have ran into some problems when trying to pass data between strongly typed views.

I have two datatypes with their own strongly typed views

Customer
Customer Site

In the index view of customer site (which returns a lits of customer sites) i need to display the customer name next to each site address, the view is strongly typed to customer site but the customer name is stored in the customer table so it wont allow me to access this directlty from the model?

I know that one option is to use the viewbag, i have successfully done this to display the Customer Name in a drop down list on my create view using the following code

Customer Site Controller/////////

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "CustomerName");
        return View();
    }
```

Index view//////////

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId,   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Id)
```

This works fine but now i need to the customer name to be inserted each table row rather than a drop down list. Can anyone kindly offer any pointers on how i can retrieve a list of customer names to be rendered in a table in the index view of the customer site?

Also is the viewbag the best way to pass data between views or are there other alternative methods? Is there a way to strongly type a view with multiple data types?

Any advice anyone can offer would be great.

Kind Regards

Liam

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that you need to combine information from two classes - Customer and CustomerSite. Is this correct?

Comment: You can create a ViewModel class that combines all the necessary information into one class. This will help keep your models very pure without limiting the functionality of your views.

Comment: @tomas - Yep, see my answer below which shows that exact principal. In fact, in my designs even if the view is only going to need a single domain entity I *always* wrap it in a ViewModel first just to make it easier to work with if later I need to pass along other information. It's a little more effort up front but pushes the idea of separation a bit more. =)

Answer (score 1):

In response to this part of your question:

> Also is the viewbag the best way to
>   pass data between views or are there
>   other alternative methods? Is there a
>   way to strongly type a view with
>   multiple data types?

The answer is Yes. Create a new class like so:

```
public class SomeViewModel {
    public Customer SomeCustomer { get; set; }

    public CustomerSite SomeCustomerSite { get; set; }
}
```

Pass that into your view which will then have access to both data types through its Model.

Comment: @Yuck Hi thanks for the quick reply, i have done this but now get errors in the view saying that the new view model doesnt contain defintions for my fields. For example,       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitNo), gives an error that someViewModel does not contain defintions for unit no?

Comment: I haven't worked with Razor yet, so your @ syntax is throwing me a bit. Everything will be nested down another layer though. Change your `foreach` loop to be Model.Customers or Model.CustomerSites - whatever you named your lists. IntelliSense should help you out with this.

Comment: @Yuck, thanks again but for some reason i cant write Model.CustomerSites, when typing model. none of my types are listed, think it may have something to with the view declaration being am IEnumerable, @model IEnumerable<trsDatabase.Models.masterViewModel>, any ideas?

Comment: @Yuck, In the for each loop i can only write Model, but that throws the "does not contain a definition error", in another view where the declaration is not an IEnumerable, e.g. @model trsDatabase.Models.Customer it does let me write Model.Customer

Comment: If you're using IEnumerable<whatever_your_viewmodel_is> then it's not going to work. If you need to pass a list, make a view model class that includes the IEnumerable within it. Then pass only a single instance of the view model into the view.

Comment: @Yuck, thanks, i have created a IEnumerable in the new View Model, eg,  public IEnumerable <CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }, and changed the declaration at the top of the view to @model trsDatabase.Models.masterViewModel, but now i get an error stating that the master viewmodel doesnt contain a defintion for get enumerator??

Comment: @Yuck, think i need to get a good book and do some more reading thanks for your advice though.

Comment: Steven Sanderson wrote a great book on MVC 2 that helped me a lot. Check out ISBN 9781430234043 which will be released at the end of this month. Based on his previous work I have high expectations for it. Good luck!